# DOM node.remove() does not invalidate Javascript Variable Reference. How to fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom, browser

I did this simple test in Chromium Console:

```
var e = document.querySelector('#myElement');
e.remove();

//But here, 'e' still references the original node even though its no longer in the DOM.
```

I don't want this behavior. I would like 'e' to act more like a Weak Reference, whereby it would change to NULL or UNDEFINED or *something* indicating the node has been destroyed.

I understand that the problem is due to the fact that the node technically still exists even though its not part of the DOM anymore. I speculate it will hang around until the browser deems an appropriate time to garbage collect it.

So instead of simply doing .remove(), is there a way to really destroy/delete the node so that all variables referencing it will become undefined or null or some effect that can be detected later?

Thanks in advance!

Also, I speculate this behavior will vary highly between browsers.  So any feedback that mentions Non-Chromium browsers is highly welcome also. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a standalone variable holds a reference to an object, and that variable can still be referenced, the object will not get picked up by the garbage collector's mark-and-sweep algorithm, and the object will continue to exist at least as long as the variable can still be referenced.

Given a reference to an object, you cannot destroy it such that other references to the object break.

JavaScript doesn't provide the sort of manual memory control you're looking for, unfortunately.

You can put the element into a WeakSet, after which removing the element from the DOM will eventually cause the element being removed from the WeakSet if nothing else can possibly reference the element - but that's not really what you're looking for.

There do exist [WeakRefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef), an *extremely* new API, which allow variables to be specially declared such that what they reference can be garbage collected despite them still being referenceable:

```
const ref = (() => {
  const e = document.querySelector('#myElement');
  const ref = new WeakRef(e);
  e.remove();
  return ref;
})();
```

With the above, calling `ref.deref()` will eventually give you `undefined` if nothing else can reference the element and it has been garbage collected. (Until it gets garbage collected, `.deref()` will give you the element.)

Comment: I notice the MDN doesn't explain WeakSets in terms of Node references. It only demonstrates objects created in js.  You mention "the DOM will eventually cause removal".  The eventually part rings true. There's no way to ensure node.remove() would also remove it from the WeakSet before other code may try to access the WeakSet. The MDN reference specifically states that timing with WeakRefs is also uncertain.  Even the code you wrote could still hold a reference to an undestroyed #myElement on return ref. Is this the correct understanding?  If so: sadness.

Comment: Yes, if something else did `const elm = document.querySelector('#myElement')` and the identifier remained referenceable (like in a closure), then running the code in the answer would not result in the element eventually getting GC'd. You'd have to have *every* place the element is retrieved use a WeakRef for it to get GC'd.

Comment: Yeah, garbage collection is asynchronous and takes some time. A few seconds at least is quite common IIRC.